# how to convert the zeros of an odd order Chebyshev Type II from low-pass prototype?

Tags: matlab, filters, infinite-impulse-response, chebyshev-filters

My DSP book (Rabiner, Lawrence R., and Bernard Gold. "Theory and application of digital signal processing." Englewood Cliffs: Prentice-Hall (1975).) has the following transformations for mapping a lowpass (analog) prototype filter to the desired filter:

Lowpass to lowpass:
$$
s_p\rightarrow\frac{s}{\Omega_u}
$$
Lowpass to highpass:
$$
s_p\rightarrow\frac{\Omega_u}{s}
$$
Lowpass to bandpass:
$$
s_p\rightarrow\frac{s^2 + \Omega_l\Omega_u}{s(\Omega_u-\Omega_l)}
$$
Lowpass to notch:
$$
s_p\rightarrow\frac{s(\Omega_u-\Omega_l)}{s^2 + \Omega_l\Omega_u}
$$
where $s_p$ is the poles and zeros of the prototype, $s$ is the poles and zeros of the desired filter and $\Omega$ are the desired cutoff frequencies.

I want to compute filter coefficients for a digital IIR filter using the Chebyshev Type II design technique in a C++ library and am verifying my results against Matlab. I have methods for calculating the prototype, computing the transformations, doing the bilinear transform and multiplying out the polynomials. It works perfectly so long as the number of poles and zeros is even.

I am 'checking by hand' with the following Matlab code:

```
Wo = .5; % cutoff as percentage of nyquist frequency
fs = 2; % matlab convention for working with digital frequencies and analog filter prototypes
uo = 2*fs*tan(pi*Wo/fs); 
order = 4;

[z,p,k] = cheb2ap(order,40); % compute prototype

zt = uo*z; % mapping low pass prototype to low pass at desired cutoff
pt = uo*p;

[ztt,ptt,ktt] = bilinear(zt,pt,k,fs); % analog to digital

btt = poly(ztt)*ktt; % multiply the roots of the z-plane polynomial to get the filter coefficients
att = poly(ptt);

[b,a] = cheby2(order,40,Wo); % check against the built in Matlab function
```

This yields identical values for the feed forward filter coefficients. The zeros are also (obviously) the same but in a different order.

```
>> b/btt
ans =

  1.000000000000001 - 0.000000000000000i
```

And such is the case when the `order` (I know it isn't the actual order of the filter, it is the order - 1) is any even value. However, if I set `order` to any odd value, the result is very nearly 4.0, which is the value I get for $\Omega_u$.

Ok, so I don't understand that at all, but at least I can work with it.

However, if I instead map to another filter type, e.g. highpass, I also get the same poles and zeros for even numbers for `order`, but for odd numbers, the zeros are off by a different value  whose meaning I can't fathom (poles are always the same):

```
Wo = .5;
fs = 2;
uo = 2*fs*tan(pi*Wo/fs);
order = 3;

[z,p,k] = cheb2ap(order,40);

zt = uo./z; % highpass mapping
pt = uo./p;

[ztt,ptt,ktt] = bilinear(zt,pt,k,fs);

btt = poly(ztt)*ktt;
att = poly(ptt);

[b,a] = cheby2(order,40,Wo, 'high')

b/btt

ans =

     2.440041381447946e-13
```

Similarly with the bandpass and notch cases (which require solving a quadratic to map the poles and zeros---so I leave it out for simplicity's sake). What's worse is that in this case, the quotient of `b/btt` changes depending on the value of `order`:

```
...
order=5;
...
b/btt
ans =

     -1.672191186690123e-13 - 1.165049447799913e-29i

...
order=7;
...
b/btt
ans =

    2.037229248854087e-13 + 1.050686044147603e-29i
```

We all know that in Chebyshev filters, if the number of zeros is odd, there will be a zero at infinite where the denominator is 0. In the Matlab's bilinear transform, this imaginary, infinite, zero gets discarded by the bilinear transform function (lines 101-102 of `bilinear.m`):

```
zs = zs(isfinite(zs));  % Strip infinities from zeros
                            % Do bilinear transformation
```

but this doesn't matter because `cheb2ap` skips the infinite zeros anyway (lines 29-35 of `cheb2ap`):

```
if isodd(n)
    m = n - 1;
    z = cos([1:2:n-2 n+2:2:2*n-1]*pi/(2*n))';
else
    m = n;
    z = cos((1:2:2*n-1)*pi/(2*n))';
end
```

and at the end of `bilinear.m` (line 118), a zero of value -1 is appended to the list of zeros so that the length matches the list of poles:

`zd = [zd1;-ones(length(pd)-length(zd1),1)];`

I suspect that here is where I need to make some kind of adjustment, but I don't know what it should be. Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Just a remark concerning your last paragraph: the zero at infinity of the analog filter is not "discarded". It is mapped to the z-plane just like all the other zeros. The bilinear transform maps infinity to $z=-1$, i.e., a zero at Nyquist.

Comment: @MattL. I am afraid that the matlab code does indeed appear to ignore zeros at the imaginary infinite value. I updated the question with references to the lines of code that do this.

Comment: Or, more accurately, Matlab's `bilinear` understands that missing zeros are infinite zeros and -1s are inserted. Which, if I am being nitpicky, is not the 'correct' implementation of a bilinear transform. It is the correct implementation of a bilinear transform when it is being used to map zeros from the s-plane to the z-plane and missing zeros are safely assumed to be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit easier to see if you look at the zeros directly and not at the numerator polynomial, i.e. `[z1,p1,k1] = cheby2(order,40,Wo, 'high');`

Odd order lowpass filters have a zero at $s=\infty$ or $z=-1$. The prototype function does NOT include this zero. For example `buttap` does not return any zeros at all.

Apparently `bilinear()` notices the missing zeros and adds them back assuming that they were are  $z=-1$.

For a high pass filter you have to manually flip the sign of that zero.

Comment: Yes indeed `bilinear.m` appends -1 to the list of zeros so that its length matches the number of poles---and I see that this is the mapping from s=inf---but the result of poly is still not the expected b coefficients.

Comment: It is for the highpass if you replace the zero at -1 with a zero at +1